# checkboxGroupInput displaying list of table elements rather than table itself

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny

I am creating an R Shiny application primarily using checkboxGroupInput where for each checkbox name I check, the corresponding table should display in the main UI panel. I have linked each checkbox option to its corresponding table (already in my previous script) in the "choices" argument of checkboxGroupInput. I use eventReactive to make a working button and renderTable to produce the appropriate tables. However, what displays in the main panel when I click the button is a list of each cell in the table rather than the table itself. This list of values looks a bit like this:

```
list(CUI = "C05372341", LAT = "ENG", TS = "P", LUI = "L0883457", STT = "PF", SUI = "S13423408", ISPREF = "N", AUI = "A10344304", SAUI = "21823712", SCUI = "1341953", SDUI = NA, SAB = "LKDHDS", TTY = "IN", CODE = "139433", STR = "Pramlintide", SRL = "0", SUPPRESS = "Y", CVF = "4354")
```

I would like this to have been printed in table form.

When I simply use renderTable({table_name}) on any given one of the tables, the table prints in the main panel how I would like it to. However, when I use eventReactive, name that variable, and renderTable on that variable, that is when the list of table values prints instead. Any ideas?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("RxNorm Diabetic Drug Mapping based on Epocrates Classes"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("drugs", "Drug Class", choices = list("ALPHA GLUCOSIDASE INHIBITORS" = agi, "AMYLIN MIMETICS" = pramlintide, "BIGUANIDES" = biguanides, "DOPAMINE AGONISTS" = bromocriptine, "DPP4 INHIBITORS" = dpp4, "GLP1 AGONISTS" = glp1, "INSULINS" = insulins, "MEGLITINIDES" = meglitinides, "SGLT2 INHIBITORS" = sglt2, "SULFONYLUREAS" = sulfonylureas, "THIAZOLIDINEDIONES" = thiazolidinediones)), 

      actionButton("button", "Retrieve Data")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("results")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
   table_reactive <- eventReactive(input$button, {
     input$drugs
   })

   output$results <- renderTable({
     table_reactive()
   })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your choices:
`choices = list("ALPHA GLUCOSIDASE INHIBITORS" = agi, "AMYLIN MIMETICS" = pramlintide ...)`, it's not valid if `agi` and `pramlintide` ... are pointing to tables. choices values can only be string.

You shouldn't pass variable as values in `checkboxGroupInput`. Instead you should pass the table name as string.

### To answer your questions:

Please see the demos below:

If your tables are saved as separate variables, you should use `sym()` and `eval_tidy()` in `rlang` package to convert string to varaible.

```
library(shiny)
library(rlang)


ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    checkboxGroupInput(
      inputId = "checkgroup",
      label = "Select Table",
      choices = list(iris = "iris", mtcars = "mtcars")
    ),
    actionButton(
      inputId = "confirm",
      label = "Confirm Table(s)"
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    tags$div(id = "tables")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$confirm,{
    removeUI(selector = "#tables > *",multiple = TRUE)
    req(length(input$checkgroup) > 0)
    for(table_name in input$checkgroup){
      table_id <- paste0("mytable",table_name)
      insertUI(
        selector = "#tables",
        ui = dataTableOutput(table_id)
      )

      output[[table_id]] <- renderDataTable(eval_tidy(sym(table_name)))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I get the same result when I separate choices into choiceNames and choiceValues.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question thoroughly. I'm modified my answer.

Comment: If I don't put choices in a list, I get this error: Error in normalizeChoicesArgs(choices, choiceNames, choiceValues) : `choiceNames` and `choiceValues` must have the same length.

Comment: Your issue is that, you can't pass a table as the choice in `checkboxGroupInput`. You should only pass the table name. I'm writing a short demo right now.

Comment: What variable do you mean? Like making the choices list look like: list("..." = "...")?

Comment: I just updated my answer. Yes, you should make your choices values as string.

Comment: I'm trying it out now. Thanks for all your help by the way. How can I integrate a button into this new code?

Comment: If it's a separate question. I suggest you create a new question and list all the details. Because it's not clear to me what you mean about integrating buttons.

Comment: The button that prints out the selected tables as detailed above.

Comment: You just need to add an action button and observe that button. I just modified my answer.